# When you want to encourage a specific quality of someone

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure

Imagine you want to encourage someone because of their "seriousness" in performing their actions and because of their persistence. What comes to my mind is just a direct translation from my language:

We would say:

> - Your seriousness is admirable.

Does it make any sense to you? If not how a native speaker would convey the same thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[dedication](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dedication)** - the quality of being dedicated or committed to a task or purpose - is an appropriate word to use in your given scenario, and can be used with the exact same wording you've provided:

> Your dedication is admirable.

If the object of this dedication isn't implicit in the conversation, we can specify it in the sentence:

> Your **dedication** to your children is admirable.
>
> Your **dedication** to your work is remarkable.
>
> I owe my life to the bravery and **dedication** of the rescue services.

If you wish to focus on their persistence, then **[perseverance](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/perseverance)** - continued effort to do or achieve something despite difficulties, failure, or opposition - can also be used to describe that attribute.

> His **perseverance** was rewarded: after many rejections, he finally found a job.

And both expressions can also be used in tandem:

> Medicine is a field which requires **dedication and perseverance**.

Comment: Can we say something like: "Your perseverance is admirable" @mike?

Comment: @A-friend - yes, that sentence would be perfectly acceptable in my opinion.

Answer (score -2):

Might I suggest [Solemnity](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/solemnity).

```
    Your solemnity is admirable.

    I appreciate your solemnity.
```

The state of being solemn is solely being serious.